# Is lifecycle event prePersist played atomically with Persist

Tags: events, doctrine-orm, lifecycle, persist

Can I assume the prePesist event and the Persist operation (related to that event) are always played in one atomic operation ?

Comment: What do you mean by "atomic operation"? If new entity is persisted then the event is always fired. Please note that persisting entity does not result in firing INSERT query, that happens during flush.

Comment: @malarzm What I mean by atomic is : Can I count entities during prePersist and be sure that no body insert/remove entites before persist operation. (I wan to be able to generate ID based on the count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not assume that. Persisting an entity fires the `prePersist` event but actual insertion is deferred until you `flush` the `EntityManager`. This means that there is a possibility for a race condition where process #1 issues INSERT query (i.e. flushes `EntityManager`) after process #2 persists entity but before `flush` is executed.